# Implementation for the read class for custom data type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a data type that I can transform into a string and back (for user input). I want a function that goes `dataToText :: Colour -> String` and the inverse function `textToData :: String -> Colour`. I came up with the following code to get this to work:

```
data Colour = Red | Blue | Green deriving (Eq, Read)
instance Show Colour where
    show Red = "R"
    show Blue = "B"
    show Green = "G"
```

When I run this in GHCi, `show Red` returns `"R"`, exactly how I want 'dataToText' to work. However, when I run `read "R"` or `read "R" :: Piece`, I get the response `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`.

I thought, but I am probably wrong, that with deriving the Read class, read will work by inverting my show function. Loading my code into GHCi doesn't give an error, so I guess some read functions must be created. I have been looking at al lot of information about read out there online, but I couldn't figure out how to do this basic read functionality. Often `readPrec` and `readsPrec` are mentioned, but I wasn't able to create a successful implementation using those. Could someone maybe explain how my example above should be implemented? I feel like I just am missing just a single (but fundamental) piece of the puzzle to understand how Read works.

Comment: I guess the default Read inverses the default Show, but it doesn't inverse a custom Show, because that's impossible.

Comment: Consider `data Colour = R | B | G deriving (Eq, Read, Show)` plus pattern synonyms `pattern Red = R`, etc.

Comment: The default `Read` and `Show` instances are both derived from the constructor names, so the fact that `read` and `show` are by default inverses is a consequence of their shared origin, not any concerted effort to *ensure* that they are inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-ddump-derive` when deriving your instance

```hs
Prelude> data Colour = Red | Blue | Green deriving Read

==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived class instances:
  instance GHC.Read.Read Ghci3.Colour where
    GHC.Read.readPrec
      = GHC.Read.parens
          (GHC.Read.choose
             [("Red", GHC.Base.return Ghci3.Red),
              ("Blue", GHC.Base.return Ghci3.Blue),
              ("Green", GHC.Base.return Ghci3.Green)])
    GHC.Read.readList = GHC.Read.readListDefault
    GHC.Read.readListPrec = GHC.Read.readListPrecDefault


Derived type family instances:



==================== Filling in method body ====================
GHC.Read.Read [Ghci3.Colour]
  GHC.Read.readsPrec = GHC.Read.$dmreadsPrec @(Ghci3.Colour)
```

Then you can easily replace the strings

```
instance Read Colour where
  readPrec :: ReadPrec Colour
  readPrec = parens $
    choose
      [ ("R", pure Red)
      , ("B", pure Blue)
      , ("G", pure Green)
      ]
```

Comment: You could set it up derive both, so they are in agreement: `deriving (Read, Show) via Constructor '["R", "B", "G"] Colour`